# How to add and replace lines in a line array with perl

Tags: perl

I want to edit a file by adding some line and replacing some others.
I'm trying to work with an array that contains my file line by line, i.e

```
    my $output_file_string = `cat $result_dir/$file`;
    my @LINES = split(/\n/, $output_file_string);
```

I have a hash table of lines that I want to find in the file, and either replace them or add additional line after them.
I wrote the following code to recognize thos lines:

```
        foreach my $myline (keys %{ $hFiles_added{$file} }) { 
            foreach my $line ( @LINES) {
                  if ($line =~ /\Q$myline\E/) {
                       ### here should be a code for adding a new line after the current line ###
                  }
             }
        }
        #### here should be a code to return the array to the output file ####
```

I can't figure how to do the adding\replacing part, and how to save my edited file back in a file (and not array

thank you
Shahar

Comment: not sure what you mean.... I need to have at the end the original file with some new lines and some raplaced lines

Comment: See [perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?)

Answer (score 3):

Use [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) to alter the contents of `@LINES`.

Use [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) to write `@LINES` back to your file.

If other people might be editing this file at the same time then you'll need [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html).

If performance isn't that important to you then you might look at [Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html).

For more complicated file handling, you might want [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) and [truncate](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html).

But this is all covered well in the Perl FAQ - [How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

By the way, your first two lines of code can be replaced with one:

```
my @LINES = `cat $result_dir/$file`;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach where file is processed line by line, and lines are modified within user specified `$edit` function.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub edit_file {
  my $func = shift;

  # perl magic for inline edit
  local @ARGV = @_;
  local $^I = "";
  local $_;

  while (<>) {
    $func->(eof(ARGV));
  }
}


my $edit = sub {
  my ($eof) = @_;

  # print to editing file
  print "[change] $_";
  if ($eof) {
    print "adding one or more line to the end of file\n";
  }
};
edit_file($edit, "file");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module File::Slurp to read, write, append, edit the lines, insert new lines in the file and many other things.

http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp 'write_file', ':edit';

my $file = './test.txt';

#The lines you want to change with their corresponding values in the hash:
my %to_edit_line = ( edit1 => "new edit 1", edit2 => "new edit 2" );

foreach my $line ( keys %to_edit_line ) {
    edit_file_lines { s/^\Q$line\E$/$to_edit_line{$line}/ } $file;
}

#The lines after you want to add a new line:
my %to_add_line = ( add1 => 'new1', add2 => 'new2' );

foreach my $line ( keys %to_add_line ) {
    edit_file_lines { s/^\Q$line\E$/$line\n$to_add_line{$line}/ } $file;
}

#The lines you want to delete:
my %to_delete_line = ( del1 => 1, del2 => 1 );

foreach my $line ( keys %to_delete_line ) {
    edit_file_lines { $_ = '' if /^\Q$line\E$/ } $file;
}

#You can also use this module to append to a file:
write_file $file, {append => 1}, "the line you want to append";

The original file test.txt had the following content:

zzz
add1
zzz
del1
zzz
edit1
zzz
add2
zzz
del2
zzz
edit2
zzz

After running the program, the same file has the following content:

zzz
add1
new1
zzz
zzz
new edit 1
zzz
add2
new2
zzz
zzz
new edit 2
zzz
the line you want to append
```