# perl Combine each two line into one line in a file

Tags: perl

I have a sample text file contain a record for key value pair, but first key in first line its value in second line, then second key in third line its value in fourth line ,

eg sample.conf in one vertical line

```
key1
value1
key2
value2
key3
value3
...
and so on
```

I need to convert it into

```
key1 = value1 
key2 = value2

or it may be 

key1    key2.........
value1  value2.....
```

please help me, i am beginner to perl, I really appreciate the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using perl one liner; remove newline for every odd line, and add `=` to the beginning for every even line,

```
perl -pe 'if ($. %2){ chomp }else{ s/^/ = / }' file
```

using similar approach,

```
perl -pe 'chomp; $_ .= " = ". <>' file
```

output

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
key3 = value3
```

or using script,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, "<", "file";
while (<$fh>) {
  if ($. %2){ chomp } else { s/^/ = / }
  print;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks, this is working, but i want it in perl script form

Comment: yes ,this is great, only one thing remain that i want to put to changes to same file, it print only on the screen and file remain unchanged

Comment: @user3887070 check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25621907/223226 and use this sub https://gist.github.com/mpapec/e324dd31e3d55e646ff9

Comment: @jaypal that's why I also wrote second one-liner `;)`

Answer (score 3):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (my $k = <DATA>) {

  chomp $k;
  my $v = <DATA>;

  print "$k = $v";

}

__DATA__
key1
value1
key2
value2
key3
value3
```

Comment: I think you intended that `print` to be a `say`.

Comment: Actually not, I want only one newline after `$v` and I didn't `chomp` `$v`. I could of course have *chomped* `$v` and then *said* `$k = $v`. But the `use feature 'say';` was superflouos;

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right, of course. I knew something didn't look right - it was the `use feature`.

Answer (score 3):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ = / if $. % 2' file
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `s/\n/ = /`: Replace the newline with a space delimited equal sign...
- `if $. % 2`: only on odd numbered lines.

#### Using a Script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

#open my $fh, '<', "file";  # To replace below line when not testing
my $fh = \*DATA;

while (<$fh>) {
    s/\n/ = / if $. % 2;
    print;
}

__DATA__
key1
value1
key2
value2
key3
value3
```

Outputs:

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
key3 = value3
```