# perl regex to abbreviate columns from file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with several lines containing headings and values.
Because the values will be inserted into a database, I'd like to use the headings to denote the column names.  So example data is below.

```
Sales-Date
Item
Sale Price
Discount
Cost of Item
Profit (loss)
```

I've already put the columns only into an array, and stripped out the parentheses and the dashes. This resulst in:

```
Sales Date
Item
Sale Price
Discount
Cost of Item
Profit loss
```

So what I need to do is come up with a regex that looks at the line, and if its One word only, return say the first 4 letters, and if its multiple words, returns the first letter of each word.  Ideally uppercase.  So the desired data would look like:

```
SD
ITEM
SP
DISC
COI
PL
```

I'm not having much luck.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;

  # If the line contains whitespace...
  if (/\s/) {
    # ... split the line into words ...
    # ... take the first letter of each word ...
    # ... join the letters together ...
    # ... and upper-case the resulting string.
    say uc join '', map { substr $_, 0, 1 } split /\s+/;
  } else {
    # ... otherwise, take the first four characters from the string ...
    # ... and upper-case them.
    say uc substr $_, 0, 4;
  }
}

__END__
Sales Date
Item
Sale Price
Discount
Cost of Item
Profit loss
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to split the line into an array by white space, than just capture each few letters of each word.  Something like:

```
my $line = "Sales Date";

# Split line into an array separated by whitespace
my @words = split /\s+/, $line;

my $letters;
# For loop through number of words in array
for (@words) {
    m/(.)/;
    $letters .= $1;
}

print $letters;
```

The above will print SD.  You can just change the m/(.)/ to represent the number of characters you would like to capture.

Comment: To capture more characters just add {x} after the (.) in the regular expression.  Of course, you could also do this with substr like toolic said - just grabbing a small substring of each word and add them to the end of letters.  You will have more control over what you grab with the match expression, however.

Answer (score 1):

```
my @arr = map {
  # make entire string upper case
  local $_ = uc;
  # remove trailing white-spaces (sometimes chomp fails on line endings)
  s/\s+\z//;

  # more words?
  /\s/
      # take first letter of every word
      ? join("", /\b(\w)/g)
      # take first 1 to 4 letters (and be greedy at that)
      : /(\w{1,4})/;
}
<DATA>;

print $_, "\n" for @arr;

__DATA__
Sales Date
Item
Sale Price
Discount
Cost of Item
Profit loss
```

output

```
SD
ITEM
SP
DISC
COI
PL
```

Comment: Thank you mpapec, what would that conver too as a perl one liner?

Comment: @user2482575 try `perl -lne '$_ =uc; print /\s/ ? join("", /\b(\w)/g) : /(\w{1,4})/' file
`

Comment: `s/(?|(?:^(\S{1,4})\S*$)|(\S)\S*\s*)/\U$1/g`

Comment: @bobbogo yes, that's it; perhaps adding `/x` and spaces to regex.

Comment: Thanks Dave and mpapec.  One more question. Since I have to do this for hundreds of files, it would be advantageous if I could do the one liners on these files before I start processing them.  Can I call the one liners from within the perl script, I tried and had a few problems and was assuming that was due to quoting and interpolation issues.

Comment: @user2482575 you can, but it is unnecessary and error prone to call one liners from main script. Instead you can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25621907/223226 if you want to do in-place file edit. `my $edit = sub { $_ =uc; print /\s/ ? join("", /\b(\w)/g) : /(\w{1,4})/ }; edit_file($edit, "your_file", "file2");`